# Finding maximum sink and source currents from datasheet

Tags: microcontroller, current-source, 8051, current-sink

How can I find the maximum sinking and sourcing currents of different pins in a microcontroller (namely 8051) from its datasheet?
Edit: I have downloaded and looked at the datasheet, I just can't read this information from it.

Comment: The one I'm looking for is AT89C51 which is a configuration of Atmel 8051

Comment: How much do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values given for V(oh) and V(ol) state the current that the device can provide and still provide reliable logic levels. For a CMOS device you can estimate the max Rds(on) for the driver  FET pair and thus establish what the theoretical maximum current would be for the pin.

There’s also a max total current specified for all the pins in aggregate, and per port. See Note 6 in the DC Characteristics, in the datasheet [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc4113.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc0265.pdf) is the uC you are referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The test method for output current is to measure the max or min voltage for a std. current level used within a logic family.

When using it for other purposes, consider the RdsOn of the CMOS discrete model.

[image]